# C symbol visibility in static archives

Tags: c, gcc, linker, visibility, symbols

I have files foo.c bar.c and baz.c, plus wrapper code myfn.c  defining a function myfn() that uses code and data from those other files.

I would like to create something like an object file or archive, myfn.o or libmyfn.a, so that myfn() can be made available to other projects without also exporting a load of symbols from {foo,bar,baz}.o as well.

What's the right way to do that in Linux/gcc?  Thanks.

---

Update: I've found one way of doing it.  I should've emphasised originally that this was about static archives, not DSOs.  Anyway, the recipe:

1. `#define PUBLIC __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))` then mark `myfn()` as `PUBLIC` in `myfn.c`.  Don't mark anything else `PUBLIC`.
2. Compile objects with `gcc -c foo.c bar.c baz.c myfn.c -fvisibility=hidden`, which marks everything as hidden except for `myfn()`.
3. Create a convenience archive using `ld`'s partial-linking switch: `ld -r foo.o bar.o baz.o myfn.o -o libmyfn.a`
4. Localise everything that wasn't `PUBLIC` like so: `objcopy --localize-hidden libmyfn.a`
5. Now `nm` says `myfn` is the only global symbol in `libmyfn.a` and subsequent linking into other programs works just fine: `gcc -o main main.c -L. -lmyfn` (here, the program calls `myfn()`; if it tried to call `foo()` then compilation would fail).

If I use `ar` instead of `ld -r` in step 3 then compilation fails in step 5: I guess `ar` hasn't linked `foo` etc to `myfn`, and no longer can once those functions are localised, whereas `ld -r` resolves the link before it gets localised-away.

**I'd welcome any response that confirms this is the "right" way, or describes a slicker way of achieving the same.**

Comment: The right way would be to find a literature or a tutorial on libraries creation.

Comment: Do me the favour of posting that as an answer, Eugene, so I can down-vote it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, C linkage for globals is all-or-nothing, in the sense that the globals of all modules would be available in `libmyfn.a`'s final list of external symbols.

`gcc` tool chain offers an extension that lets you hide symbols from outside users, while making them available to other translation units in your library:

foo.h:

```
void foo();
```

foo.c:

```
void foo() __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")));
```

myfn.h:

```
void myfn();
```

myfn.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

void myfn() {
    printf("calling foo...\n");
    foo();
    printf("calling foo again...\n");
    foo();
}
```

For portability, you would probably benefit from making a macro for `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))`, and placing it in a conditional compilation block conditioned on `gcc`.

In addition, Linux offers a [utility called `strip`](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/09/strip-command-examples/), which lets you remove some of the symbols from compiled object files. Options `-N` and `-K` let you identify individual symbols that you want to keep or remove.

Comment: This seems the response closest to my original, not-very-well-phrased, question.  Perhaps you could take a look again at the question now I've edited it and let me know what you think of the proposed solution?

Comment: @PythonAteMyHamster Your new approach of marking some functions public and stripping everything else looks right.

Comment: I'll give it an hour, but if no-one posts anything better then you get the right-answer tick.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this to build a static library

```
gcc -c -O2 foo.c bar.c baz.c myfn.c
ar av libmyfunctions.a foo.o bar.o baz.o myfn.o
```

Compile and link with other programs like:

```
gcc -O2 program.c -lmyfunctions -o myprogram
```

Now your `libmyfunctions.a` will ultimately have extra stuff from the source that isn't required by the code in myfn.c  But the linker should do a reasonable job of removing this when it creates the final program.

Comment: Thanks selbie, but that "extra stuff" was exactly the problem I was trying to remove when I asked the question!

Comment: The linker will remove unused object code for you.  But if you are trying to minimize the size of your .lib file, then you'll need to have a custom build. (e.g. `#define LIBRARY_BUILD 1`, and then code not meant for the build is under #ifndef `LIBRARY_BUILD` sections.

Comment: This wasn't about controlling what object code the linker pulls-in, selbie, it was about restricting visibility of symbols in libmyfn.a to just those representing the API (and not all the other functions implementing the API).  My updated post now shows one way of achieving what I wanted.  Thanks all the same.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose myfn.c has function myfun() which you want to use in other three files foo.c, bar.c & baz.c

Now create a shared library from code in myfn.c viz libmyf.a

Use this function call myfun() in other three files. Declare function as extern in these files. Now you can create object code of these thee files and link the libmyf.a at linking phase.

Refer to following link for using shared libraries.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, but I know basically how to build libraries; what I didn't know was how to control symbol visibility.  I think I've got it now.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility
Above page confirms your solution and also provide another method using #pragmas.